# RequestCycle goes null when using a separate thread

Tags: multithreading, wicket

I am using a separate thread to handle the processing of a file. The main thread holds the table to display to the user using a listView, and uses an AjaxSelfUpdatingTimer to refresh the list every second.

The problem is, after processing about 100 lines in my CSV file, I keep getting a no requestCyle exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No RequestCycle is currently set!
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getRequest(Component.java:1804)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.dirty(WebPage.java:318)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.dirty(Page.java:249)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.componentStateChanging(Page.java:926)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.addStateChange(Component.java:3528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.error(Component.java:1225)
    at com.wicket.BulkLoadPage$BatchLoaderProcessingThread.processLine(BulkLoadPage.java:806)
    at com.wicket.BulkLoadPage$BatchLoaderProcessingThread.run(BulkLoadPage.java:674)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

these are my runnable classes the thread calls:

```
class BatchLoaderProcessingThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        processLine();
        loaderFinished();
    }   

    public void cancelThread()
    {
        cancelLoaderThread = true;
    }   
}       

class BatchDeleteProcessingThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        processLine();
        deleterFinished();
    }   

    public void cancelThread()
    {
        cancelDeleterThread = true;
    }   
}
```

I don't understand why the requestCycle would just go null.. How can I prevent this from happening?

Edit:

Commenting out feedback message do troubleshoot requestRecycle error, I receive this error:

```
    java.io.IOException: Read error
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:185)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:261)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)

    Dec 30 13:14:31 ERROR BulkLoadPage-java.io.IOException: Read error
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader.getNextLine(CSVReader.java:266)
at au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader.readNext(CSVReader.java:233)
at com..wicket.BulkLoadPage.processLine(BulkLoadPage.java:547)
at com..wicket.BulkLoadPage.access$0(BulkLoadPage.java:532)
at     

    com..wicket.BulkLoadPage$BatchLoaderProcessingThread.run(BulkLoadPage.java:1294)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

this error only occurs with the larger file as well. All of the lines inside the csv are duplicate only to mimic a large file.. so all lines are the same, and there shouldn't be an error caused directly from the file. Is there something else that I should be looking for that would cause this error from using another thread?

Comment: Why would your Thread need to know the RequestCycle? I can imagine that the AjaxTimer knows the Thread and asks it every second for a status update (which will then most likely lead to Serialization problems). If you're using Wicket 6+ you might want to take a look into the EventBus (then the Worker-Thread could push messages to your Page and it would react to them)

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look into that. I am not sure why the thread would need to know about the requestCycle, but I only get that error when using another thread. I don't fully understand the requestCycle and have been looking for more information on it. I have found some Api documents but it doesn't fully explain, how it is started and how it ends when using another thread. What confuses me most is how it works when it reads in 50 lines or so but gives that error when it has to loop through many more lines inside the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestCycle is a thread local singleton. If you're running a process in another thread that really means the RequestCycle singleton doesn't exist in your new thread.

The following example is placed on https://repo.twinstone.org/projects/WISTF/repos/wicket-examples-1.4/browse

The idea is about holding the reference to the current RequestCycle, you cannot call RequestCycle.get() due to the thread local singleton doesn't exist in any other thread. This CustomRequestCycle implementation is ever waiting until the new thread notify its finishing. The counter of loops is just a protection to do not freeze the primary thread if the WaitingRunnable stops working/freezes.

**RESULTS oF TESTS:**

Check your logs for **case 1**, the separate thread is finishing very soon, **RequestCycle doesn't wait for detaching**

```
http://localhost:8080/wicket-examples14/wait?millis=10
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 0
INFO  - WaitingRunnableNotifier    - Separate thread waiting finished cz.wicketstuff.enteam.wicket.examples14.request.ThreadWaitingPage
INFO  - CustomRequestCycle         - Notifier returned: Successfully finished
```

Check your logs for **case 2**, the separate thread is finishing in time, **RequestCycle has to wait for detaching**

```
http://localhost:8080/wicket-examples14/wait?millis=3000
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 0
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 1
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 2
INFO  - WaitingRunnableNotifier    - Separate thread waiting finished cz.wicketstuff.enteam.wicket.examples14.request.ThreadWaitingPage
INFO  - CustomRequestCycle         - Notifier returned: Successfully finished
```

Check your logs for **case 3**, the separate thread is finishing on time, **RequestCycle is already detached**

```
http://localhost:8080/wicket-examples14/wait?millis=10000
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 0
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 1
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 2
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 3
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 4
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 5
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 6
DEBUG - CustomRequestCycle         - Waiting until notify: 7
INFO  - CustomRequestCycle         - Notifier returned: null
INFO  - WaitingRunnableNotifier    - Separate thread waiting finished cz.wicketstuff.enteam.wicket.examples14.request.ThreadWaitingPage
```

---

**SOURCES:**

**WicketApplication**

```
@Override
public RequestCycle newRequestCycle(Request request, Response response) {
    return new CustomRequestCycle(this, (WebRequest)request, (WebResponse)response);
}
```

**CustomRequestCycle**

```
public class CustomRequestCycle extends WebRequestCycle implements INotifier<String> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRequestCycle.class);

    private long sleepTime = 1000L;
    private long maxLoops = 8;

    private boolean canDetach = true;
    private String notifierResult;

    public CustomRequestCycle(WicketApplication application, WebRequest request,
            Response response) {
        super(application, request, response);
    }

    public void notifyAny(String payload) {
        notifierResult = payload;
        canDetach = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
        long counter = 0;
        while(!canDetach && maxLoops > counter) {
            log.debug("Waiting until notify: " + counter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            }
            counter++;
        }
        log.info("Notifier returned: " + notifierResult);
        super.detach();
    }

    public static CustomRequestCycle get() {
        return (CustomRequestCycle)RequestCycle.get();
    }

    /**
     * @return the canDetach
     */
    public boolean isCanDetach() {
        return canDetach;
    }

    /**
     * @param canDetach the canDetach to set
     */
    public void setCanDetach(boolean canDetach) {
        this.canDetach = canDetach;
    }


}
```

**WaitingRunnableNotifier**

```
public class WaitingRunnableNotifier implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WaitingRunnableNotifier.class);

    private final long waitTime;

    private RequestCycle requestCycle;
    private INotifier<String> notifier;

    public WaitingRunnableNotifier(RequestCycle requestCycle, long waitTime, INotifier<String> notifier) {
        super();
        this.notifier = notifier;
        this.requestCycle = requestCycle;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }

    public void run() {
        String message = null;
        try {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }           
            log.info("Separate thread waiting finished " + requestCycle.getResponsePageClass().getCanonicalName());
            message = "Successfully finished";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception during WaitingRunnableNotifier.run()", e);
            message = "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            notifier.notifyAny(message);
            clean();
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Clean object references
     */
    private void clean() {
        requestCycle = null;
        notifier = null;        
    }   

}
```

**ThreadWaitingPage** is a page with parameter 'millis'. There you can invoke the another thread and wait unitl it is finished.

```
public class ThreadWaitingPage extends WebPage {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final long millis;

    public ThreadWaitingPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
        millis = parameters.getLong("millis");
        add(new Label("millis", String.valueOf(millis)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();
        CustomRequestCycle requestCycle = CustomRequestCycle.get();
        requestCycle.setCanDetach(false);
        new Thread(new WaitingRunnableNotifier(requestCycle, millis, requestCycle)).start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Also, how come it works for a small amount of rows in the csv files, but only fails with large amounts?

Comment: Hmm, first thing first, you have to reference the current RequestCycle. The second think is that if the request is finished and a response is returned, the RequestCycle is detached, then also the same exception will be thrown. It could be the same trouble in your case.

Comment: Sounds beyond my knowledge of wicket. I was able to reference the current RequestCycle but I am not sure how to attach it to the new thread. I wish Wicket was more thread friendly.

Comment: Well, Wicket is very complex solution of component framework and there many thing to prevent memory leaks or wasting memory, so it is very important to understand the live cycle of component, request and application, because it is often helpful. I don't know the whole problem you really solve but the result of this discussion is to wait by RequestCycle until your job is finishing, or do not use RequestCycle in your job in a separate thread.

Comment: I am not sure how to wait by the RequestCycle or avoid using it.  

reading here: http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/RequestCycle.html

gives me some ideas about what it is used for, but when is it actually invoked? and what would cause it to detach itself.

Comment: In Wicket 1.4: Write your own RequestCycle that is a descendant of WebRequestCycle, override the detach() method and override the factory method newRequestCycle in your WebApplication. Implement an algorithm in your WebRequestCycle.detach() that is waiting until other threads are finished, then call super.detach() of the original  WebRequestCycle.detach(). The RequestCycle lifecycle is attach, process, detach :-) If you require I can add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks you :) Yes go ahead and add it please. I am confused on if I write my own RequestCycle, how do I add it to the page?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you shouldn't be creating your own threads, the container should be left to do all that for you. Of course, this means you can't leave bulk processes running in the background between requests.

I've done something similar before (breaking the rule I just mentioned!) and the easiest way is to keep Wicket out of your own threads. If your threads populate a List for example, and your ajax timer callback extracts the records from the list and adds them to the list view.

The problem with list views though is you have to add the parent component to the ajax request target, meaning that the whole list view will be sent back in the ajax response, not just the new entries you've added but all the old ones as well, which would defeat the point of loading them incrementally.

As its only a CSV file, it might be better for you to use a data table, and write a data provider to open the file and read only the records for that request which should be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks taroquud. Yes I currently use the threads without Wicket. Basically it just calls a method which reads in one line and processes it, and stores the values into an object. These objects are then stored in an arrayList (which is stored in the main thread), and the listView uses this arrayList which is updated every second by the ajaxSelfUpdatingTimer. But like you said, the whole list is getting refreshed each time, as opposed to just the new entries. I will be back to work on Thursday where I will invest more time into this (I am just being proactive beforehand), and I will look into...

Comment: creating a data table and its provider. Having it my current way though, do you know what would cause the requestCycle error only during larger sized csv files as opposed to smaller ones? Does it have something to do with synchronization issues? Or possibly data interleave?

Comment: Your stack trace suggests you're calling the error method of something that extends Component from within your thread which is causing the problem. If you need to add things to a feedback panel, it might be better if you put all the error strings into a list from your thread, and then pull then from the list in an onbeforerender and call error in there instead.

Comment: Thanks, When I remove that line I also get a read error, which I have edit in my original response. See above.

Answer (score 1):

I have temporarily fixed this issue by first loading the lines into a string ArrayList in the main thread and just read from that list inside the thread..

I don't really see any latency issues, so maybe this can be considered a good alternative? If it isn't please let me know, otherwise hopefully this helps someone else some day who struggles with this.

I have also posted my issue here:
http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/MultiThreading-issues-with-Wicket-td4663325.html#a4663389

and was given some good resource links to review:

Multithreading in wicket:

http://javathoughts.capesugarbird.com/2008/04/spawning-thread-for-lengthy-operation.html

RequestCycle:
http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/chapter8.html